# Pointer is not initialized?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

In my main class, I have a person object, which, in the person class,
contains a pointer to a Strategy object. I'm trying to do this:

```
person.strategyPointer->getStrategyType()
```

But when I print this out, I get a special number, 3435973836. This
probably means my strategyPointer has not been initialized.

In my Person class header file, I declare this:

```
Strategy* strategyPointer;
```

And in the Person.cpp file I initialize the pointer like this.

```
Person::Person()
    : strategyPointer(nullptr)
{
}
```

If I point the pointer to null, why is the compiler still complaining that
I don't have the strategyPointer initialized? Or perhaps since it points
to null, it falls out of scope and gets deleted? I actually point the
pointer to something when I'm parsing. I do something like this:

```
StrategyType newStrat;
newStrat.setStrategyType(strategyType);
    person.strategyPointer = &newStrat
```

I'm using inheritance, and Strategy is my base class. However, it complains about
initialization later on back in my main source file. I have no idea what's
going on with this initialization problem. I can't point the pointer to a
bogus Strategy object either.

EDIT:
I have just added a new variable declaration in my Person header file, 
Strategy newStrategy;
I later assign the StrategyType object which I've created into newStrategy, and I point strategyPointer to &newStrategy. This should prevent the StrategyType object that I've created from falling out of scope, right? But in my main.cpp I still get the same value when I try to print out person.stratPointer->getStrategyType(); However, if I print out person.newStrategy.getStrategyType(), I get the value which I want.

Comment: You might want to provide more details if you hope to get an answer like what programming language ... ?

Comment: Post the exact error message. Compilers don't usually complain about uninitialized variables, that's usually a runtime problem.

Comment: @EddieB Since he said the source file was named Person.cpp, I've added the c++ tag.

Comment: You declare strategyPointer to be `Strategy*`, but in your last line you're pointing it to a `StrategyType`, not `Strategy`. Is one of those a typo?

Comment: Your constructor initializes `Person::strategyPointer`, but based on the first code sample, you're seeing a different variable, `StrategyType::strategyType`, as uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is your intention to dereference a NULL pointer (and if it is, get your head examined), your definition of "initialized" is only accurate in the sense that setting the pointer to `nullptr` in the initializer list of the Person constructor avoid its value being indeterminate.

That said, this screams of ???

```
StrategyType newStrat;
newStrat.setStrategyType(strategyType);
person.strategyPointer = &newStrat;
```

If this is in a function somewhere (and it certainly must be) the moment `newStrat` goes out of scope on function return, loop exit, etc, your `person` object now references undefined behavior. It would also explain why you're seeing the  stack-marker as the result value.

Make StrategyType a value-property of Person and initialize it like this:

```
person.strategy.setStrategyType(strategyType);
```

Or better still like this:

```
class Person
{
   ...
   StrategyType strategy;

public:
   void setStrategyType(StrategyType type)
   {
       strategyType.setStrategyType(type);
   }
};
```